# How to use view and template based on language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, internationalization, high-voltage

I am using [`high_voltage`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) to create multiple landing pages.

**Structure**

```
app
  views
    pages
      home.html.erb
      about.html.erb
```

I would like to be able in simple way to use different view template according on `session[:locale]`

I thought about structure like this:

```
app
  views
    pages
      en
        home.html.erb
      es
        home.html.erb
```

But how then render correct template in PagesController?

I dont want to use Rails internationalization(I18n) gem for this.

I am saving `I18n.locale` in a Session using `set_language_controller`.
Source: http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/i18n_mehrsprachige_rails_applikation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just name the files as:

```
app
  views
    pages
      home.html.en.erb
      home.html.es.erb
      about.html.en.erb
      about.html.es.erb
```

Comment: But then I can't use for ex: ``/home`` as route to home action